# Why do LC filters have 40 dB/decade ripple attenuation at high frequencies?

Tags: filter, bode-plot, emi-filtering

I am taking an online course on power electronics in which I encountered the following concept which I couldn't understand.

The instructor had the following comment about the following grid interface input filters:

[image]

- The filter in Fig.1 will have high losses at low frequencies, but its advantage is that at high frequencies the current ripples are attenuated at 40 dB/decade.
- The filter in Fig.2 will have low losses at low frequencies, but its drawback is that at high frequencies the current ripples are attenuated at only 20 dB.
- The filter in Fig.3 is the best of both worlds, because it doesn't dissipate much loss in low frequencies, and it has 40 dB/decade ripple attenuation at high frequencies.

I understand the loss part, but I don't get how the instructor concluded that attenuation is 40 dB/decade for fig.1.

I made this graphical representation of the impedance Bode plot:

[image]

If my Bode plot is correct, then at high frequencies, only 20dB/decade will be attenuated. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand the loss part, but I don't get how the instructor concluded that attenuation is 40 dB/decade for fig.1.

> I made this graphical representation of the impedance Bode plot:

Use gain bode plot rather than impedance bode plot to see where that 40dB/dec attenuation comes from. If you write the gain transfer function of the 1st circuit you'll see that it'll be in the following form:

$$
H(s) = \frac{\omega_n^2}{s^2+2\zeta\omega_ns+\omega_n^2}
$$

This transfer function has a double pole at \$\omega_n=1/\sqrt{L_f C_f}\$ which is called natural frequency or resonance frequency. A single pole brings -20 dB/dec (i.e. an attenuation of 20 dB/dec), so a double one does -40dB/dec.

Answer (score 1):

The Bode plot is incorrect.

LC filters are second order filters. Second order filters have 40 dB/decade attenuation.

First order filters, such as RC filters have 20 dB/decade attenuation.